# How can I calibrate a joystick on a Mac?

Tags: controllers, macos

A joystick on my controller is off-center, and I don't want to go through the pain of fixing it (it has proprietary screws, plus I don't know what to do with it once I'm inside). How do I go about fixing this?

FYI: I *have* tried [YsJoystickCalibrator](http://ysflight.in.coocan.jp/programming/macosx/joystick/e.html) to no avail. I am also trying to use [Enjoy2](https://github.com/fyhuang/enjoy2), which has no calibration tool AFAIK.